# Jmeter Groovy class properties

Tags: groovy, jmeter

In my Jmeter script at the beginning of the thread I have defined a class and a  list array of those that class:

```
class TempClass{
   String Name;
   String Prop1;
}
props.put("TempClass", TempClass);
ArrayList<TempClass> tempList = new ArrayList<TempClass>();
vars.putObject("tempList", tempList);
```

I would like instantiate that class on one of the HTTP Req. post Processor with Groovy, then add its properties and add that class to an array of those classes.

i.e

```
//def t1 = new TempClass();
t1 = props.get("TempClass");
t1.Name= "Suzie";
t1.Prop1 = "3";


tempList = vars.getObject("tempList");    
tempList.add(t1);  
vars.putObject("tempList", tempList);
```

I get an error when I instantiate the class:

```
 No such property: Name for class: TempClass
```

Please help thanks

Comment: In your class you start with an uppercase `N` for your property, so I'd suggest to change it to lowercase.

Comment: thanks It was a typo I just fixed it, that is not the issue

Comment: I suggest you debug or output class of t1. It may be some kind of stub, not expected TempClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code should be:

```
class TempClass{
   String name;
   String prop1;
}
props.put("TempClass", new TempClass());
ArrayList<TempClass> tempList = new ArrayList<TempClass>();
vars.putObject("tempList", tempList);
```

Then:

```
def t1 = props.get("TempClass");
t1.name= "Suzie";
t1.prop1 = "3";
tempList = vars.getObject("tempList");    
tempList.add(t1);  
vars.putObject("tempList", tempList);
```

Few notes about JMeter as I am not sure what you are trying to do:

- Properties (props) are shared accross threads
- Variables are specific to each user

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: so if I wanted to instantiate two     def t2 = props.get("TempClass");
t2.name= "Suzie2";
t2.prop1 = "5";  It looks like the 2nd is overwriting the first?

Comment: yes. But even if you use vars, ensure you name the key differently

Comment: Can you pls help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726344/jmeter-groovy-list-of-classes-instantiating